# Visual basic code for login form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have two fields, username and password, currently there are two users, my code only accepts the 1st user's username and password, but not the second user. Cant seem to figure out where i should make the changes. I get an error in ms access related to duplicate data entry.

Please tell me what i can do to change my code, currently my visual basic code logic is, if username and password are entered correctly then open a form

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click()

    Set L = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Login")

    'validation to check if the user entered the username in the username field

    If IsNull(Me.txtUsername) Or Me.txtUsername = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'validation to check if the user entered the password in the password field

    If IsNull(Me.strPassword) Or Me.strPassword = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'check to see if the password and username match


    If (Me.txtUsername = L.[Username]) And (Me.strPassword = L.[Password]) Then


        'Close Member login form and open the member form


        DoCmd.OpenForm "Memberform"

    Else
        MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and where you have gotten stuck.

Comment: "Please tell me what i can do to change my code": Show your code. State what you've tried and what errors you are getting, etc.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Hi guys, this is the code, cant seem to figure out why i get the ms access error for duplicate entry.

Comment: @user3133036 If it is not accepting second user specific data means, they must not be matching with the data in db. Possibilities are 1. they have trailing spaces either in input or in database. 2. They are case sensitive. 3. comparing after retrieval from db, but in a wrong way. You should open up and disclose all such operations you tried in your posting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is the last If block: you're opening the Login table (or query?) but you're only looking at the first record, instead of looping through all the records to check if there's a match.

So, you could fix this by changing it to loop through the records until you find a match (not recommended), or you could instead make a query whose criteria are the supplied username and password and see if any records are returned.

## **Way 1 - looping through records:**

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click()

    'validation to check if the user entered the username in the username field

    If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Or Me.txtUserName = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'validation to check if the user entered the password in the password field

    If IsNull(Me.strPassword) Or Me.strPassword = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check to see if the password and username match

    Set L = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Login")
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    If L.BOF And L.EOF Then
        MsgBox "There are no usernames or passwords in the database.", vbOKOnly, "No login info"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Do While Not L.EOF
            If (Me.txtUserName = L.[UserName]) And (Me.strPassword = L.[Password]) Then
                found = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            L.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    If L.EOF And Not found Then
        ' at the last record and did not find a match
        MsgBox "Invalid username or password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus

        ' clean up
        L.Close
        Set L = Nothing
    Else
        ' we found a match; close Member login form and open the member form

        ' clean up
        L.Close
        Set L = Nothing

        DoCmd.OpenForm "Memberform"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If

End Sub
```

## **Way 2 - a query:**

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click()

    'validation to check if the user entered the username in the username field

    If IsNull(Me.txtUsername) Or Me.txtUsername = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a User Name.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'validation to check if the user entered the password in the password field

    If IsNull(Me.strPassword) Or Me.strPassword = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check to see if the password and username match

    ' Using a QueryDef with parameters to avoid SQL injection
    Dim qdf as DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("","SELECT Username, Password FROM Login WHERE Username=[_uname] AND Password=[_pw]")
    qdf.Parameters("_uname") = Me.txtUsername
    qdf.Parameters("_pw") = Me.strPassword

    Set L = qdf.OpenRecordset

    If L.BOF And L.EOF Then
        ' no match
        MsgBox "Invalid username or password. Please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
        Me.strPassword.SetFocus

        ' clean up
        L.Close
        Set L = Nothing
    Else
        ' we found a match; close Member login form and open the member form

        'clean up
        L.Close
        Set L = Nothing

        DoCmd.OpenForm "Memberform"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If

End Sub
```